# How to simplify this ln?

Tags: integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

I am solving this problem

$$\int {\frac{1}{\sqrt{9x^{2}-25}}dx}$$

the step I got stuck,

$$\frac13 \ln{\left(\frac{3x+\sqrt{9x^2-25}}{3}\right)} $$

and in my textbook the answer was $\frac13 (\ln{{(3x+\sqrt{9x^2-25})}}) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\ln 3$ is a constant, so it will be absorbed by the constant $C$ in the antiderivative.

Comment: got your point :).